# Why do I have an undefined reference error when linking for an object in the same archive?

Tags: c++, c, gnu-make, static-linking, binutils

I have a C++ source `mycpp.cpp` and a C source `myc.c`. The C source contains a function `myCFunc()`, which is called from the C++:

```cpp
extern "C"
{
#include "my_c.h"
}

void aCppFunction()
{
    myCFunc(stuff, and, things);
    ...
}
```

The two sources are compiled (to .o), and then archived (to .a), and then indexed, so no linking occurs:

```
ar qc thing.a *.o
ranlib thing.a
```

Later in the wider software build, this component archive is linked into a binary, and I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /path/to/mycpp.cpp:55: undefined reference to `myCFunc(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
```

I have extracted `thing.a` and can quite clearly see `myc.c.o` and `mycpp.cpp.o`, so I search them for the function:

```
> nm myc.c.o | grep myCFunc
00000000000001d0 T myCFunc
> nm -C mycpp.cpp.o | grep myCFunc
                 U myCFunc(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)
```

Can you see what is happening here? Why does the `nm` result for the C++ include the list of argument types, but the C result not? It seems to me that the function `myCFunc()` is defined in `myc.c.o`, which is part of `thing.a` along with `mycpp.cpp.o`, and that `myCFunc`'s header is included correctly.

Please help!

Comment: Clearly, the caller of `myCFunc` does not see that name as `extern "C"`, because the error message contains the parameter types. If it were seen as `extern "C"`, the error message would only say `undefined reference to myCFunc`.

Comment: Thank you! I am not a C++ guy, and that is a tremendous help.

Answer (score 0):

The unlikely answer, based on *j6t's* invaluable comment:

> Clearly, the caller of myCFunc does not see that name as extern "C", because the error message contains the parameter types. If it were seen as extern "C", the error message would only say undefined reference to myCFunc. – j6t

... is that what I did not show above, due to my C++ inexperience, is that the C header was included at the end of a train of other C++ headers, without using `extern "C"`.

Comment: Since everything is under your control, the conventional way to avoid such issues would be to put the `extern "C"` declaration into the header, with appropriate condition-compilation guards, so that both C and C++ clients can just `#include` it.